# clearing cache from multiple servers behind load balancer

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, caching, jax-rs

We have a restful webservice. We are using JaxRs's CacheControl to cache the response xml for a GET endpoint.

ex: GET - https://api.apiway.com/v1/users/12345

To Clear the cache, I need to hit the same endpoint but with a PUT(Instead of a GET) and the cache will be cleared for that endpoint.

ex: PUT - https://api.apiway.com/v1/users/12345

This works fine when I run it in my local where I only have 1 websphere instance running. But our QA environment has 2 webphere instances running behind a load balancer. So, when I call the PUT endpoint to refresh the cache, it will only clear the cache on 1 websphere instance where as the other websphere instance will send respond with outdated data.

How to I use cacheControl to refresh cache from multiple instances that are behind a load balancer?

Comment: How are you maintaining this cache?

Comment: It is cached on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few solutions available to you.  When one node gets the request to clear cache, you can put a message on a JMS topic and allow all nodes to read that message to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is exact business logic, since you have not explained it. But, for now below are some of the ways came in mind.

1. Use distributed cache (radius) update from any instance will reflect for all instances. - Recommended.
2. Use pool based cache update, every server will pool on DB to find updates/deletes. Not recommended as it could be expensive operation as cache size increases.
3. Post updated on messaging platforms such as KAFKA and let each instance have a consumer registered to update local cache.
4. If using service registry, read all server IP address and skip LB call - Not recommended.

Answer (score -2):

In short, **you cannot do this**. You cannot control which backend server instance will be forwarded with your request to clear cache. That's why we have the load balancer after all, isn't it? The LB controls where (to which server) the request goes.

*On a side note*, why would you want to clear the caches from the front-office setup, i.e. via the LB? You must have systems to clear the cache from within the back-office, that is from a system that sits next to the app server, and can reach both the app servers without the LB.

Comment: With LBs in place, this could be common situation one will land, there are multiple ways to solve this problem. Above explanation is perfectly fine but do not answer question.